# Prove that the multiples of two orthogonal eigenvectors with a matrix are also orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

I'm having trouble with this problem, I'm lost as to how to approach it.

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix, and suppose $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are orthogonal eigenvectors of $A^TA$. Show that $A\mathbf{v}$ and $A\mathbf{w}$ are orthogonal.

I can prove that the transpose of $A$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$, but I'm unsure how that might be helpful as they can have different eigenvectors. Any advice?

Comment: observe that $<Av, Aw> = <v, A^T A w> = <v, \lambda w> = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the inner product is $u^Tv$:
$$
(Av)^T(Aw)=v^TA^TAw=\lambda v^Tw=0
$$
So $Av$ and $Aw$ are orthogonal, notice how you need not use the fact that $v$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Inner product of $Av$ and $Aw$ is $(Av)^{T}Aw=v^{T}A^{T}Aw=v^{T}\lambda w$, where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $w$. Hence, the inner product is $\lambda v^{T}w=0$.