# If $w_1, w_2$ are eigenvectors of $A^TA$ associated with different eigenvalues, then $Aw_1$ is orthogonal to $Aw_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> if $w_1, w_2$ are eigenvectors of $A^TA$ associated with different eigenvalues. How to show $Aw_1$ is orthogonal to $Aw_2$

I would like to use the SVD factorization to prove this statement. Is it correct to say if $w_1,w_2$ are eigenvectors of $A^TA$ then exists a SVD $A=USV^T$ such that $w_1,w_2$ are normalized in any of the columns of $V$ ?

Comment: Note that $A^TA$ is a symmetric matrix so spectral theorem gives you.....

Comment: If you would consider proving this without using SVD, then a (vague) hint would be to write down the definition of orthogonality between $Aw_1$ and $Aw_2$ and manipulate the expression so you get something involving $(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the multiples of two orthogonal eigenvectors with a matrix are also orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784701/prove-that-the-multiples-of-two-orthogonal-eigenvectors-with-a-matrix-are-also-o) (together with [this wellknown fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal) alluded to by @Anurag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To spell it out, suppose that $w_1$ and $w_2$ are eigenvectors of $A^T A$, and suppose that the corresponding eigenvalues are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, with $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$.

Then
$$ \lambda_1 w_1^T w_2 = \left( A^T A w_1 \right)^T w_2  = w_1^T A^T A w_2 = w_1^T \left( A^T A w_2 \right) = \lambda_2 w_1^T w_2.$$
Since $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$, we must have
$$ w_1^T w_2 = 0.$$

Now
$$ (Aw_1) . (Aw_2) = (Aw_1)^T (Aw_2) = w_1^T A^T A w_2,$$
but by the calculation above, we have
$$ w_1^T A^T A w_2 = \lambda_1 w_1^T w_2 = 0, $$
so
$$ (Aw_1) . (Aw_2)  = 0.$$